# Read Named values from the context in Azure Apim

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm defining a inbound policy and trying to construct a URL from 2 components. I know how to get these values 1 but 1 but when I have to combine them into one cant figure out the syntax.

First I call a api and save the response

```
<send-request mode="copy" response-variable-name="createdUser" timeout="20" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>{{Systems.One.Endpoint}}/services/rest</set-url>
</send-request>
```

I can trace my response is ok like this

```
<trace source="Contact Id">@(((IResponse)context.Variables["createdUser"]).Body.As<JObject>()["contactId"])</trace>
```

But I dont know how to create a url from  the {{System.One.Endpoint}} and  the @(((IResponse)context.Variables["createdUser"]).Body.As()["contactId"])

This here does not work

```
<send-request mode="copy" response-variable-name="createPeriod" timeout="seconds" ignore-error="true">
 <set-url>
        {{System.Two.Endpoint}}/api/@(((IResponse)context.Variables["createPeriod"]).Body.As<JObject>()["contactId"])/createperiod/{{DefaultPeriodlength}}
</set-url>
```

Everything after the @ is just being set as string and not loaded from the actual value form the variable

How can I combine these two values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Policy expressions can only be used to produce whole value for element/attribute. Named values in contract can be used to represent any part of any attribute/element value, and are inserted into policy prior to it being analyzed/executed.So something like this:

```
<set-url>@("{{System.Two.Endpoint}}/api/" + ((IResponse)context.Variables["createPeriod"]).Body.As<JObject>()["contactId"].ToString() + "/createperiod/{{DefaultPeriodlength}}")</set-url>
```

or if you prefer string interpolation:

```
<set-url>@($"{{System.Two.Endpoint}}/api/{((IResponse)context.Variables["createPeriod"]).Body.As<JObject>()["contactId"]}/createperiod/{{DefaultPeriodlength}}")</set-url>
```

Comment: That does not even look that hard. I first successfully copied the Named Value to a Variables but this is way more pretty